# Use simple Php mail function in laravel instead of SMTP in Hostgator

Tags: laravel

> I want to use simple php mail function in laravel (using hostgator hosting) instead of smtp what
>   changes should i do in mail.php and .env to achieve  it in
>   Hostgator

**.env file**

> ```
>   MAIL_DRIVER=mail
>   MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomail.com
>   MAIL_PORT=587 
>         MAIL_USERNAME=my email address 
>   MAIL_PASSWORD=email password
>         MAIL_ENCRYPTION=none //as SSL is disabled
> ```
>
> I want to implement php mail function in laravel but due to some reason its not working although when i run simple php script i.e
>   **SIMPLE PHP SCRIPT that i tested with hostgator it is sending mail I just want to implement the same using laravel**
>           Below is my **index.php**

```
   $to = "mailhostingserver@gmail.com";
   $subject = "This is subject"; 
   $message = "This is simple text message."; 
   $header = "From:support@domain.in \r\n"; 
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header); 
   if( $retval == true ) 
   { 
   echo "Message sent successfully...";
   } 
   else { echo "Message could not be sent..."; } ?>
```

I just want to implement the above index.php code in laravel

Comment: Your .env file is in production? If not, you have to change mail driver in mail.php config file to 'mail'.

Comment: If you use `mail` then you don't need to supply anything except for that which specifies `env()` inside of `config/mail.php`. Even then, username/password are not required, nor is encryption.